# Why does VS Code 1.75 move focus to the terminal when running selected text?

Tags: visual-studio-code

A few days ago VS Code recently self-updated to version 1.75.0 and the functionality of `runSelectedText` seems to have changed.

Previously, as I recall, if this command was called, highlighted text would be run in terminal without the cursor moving. Now, if this command is run, the cursor jumps from the editor to the terminal. I would like to either (i) change a setting somewhere (if it exists) so that this command doesn't jump to the terminal, or, (ii) work out a way of returning the cursor to the editor (e.g., with a macro).

I previously had this as part of a macro to highlight the current line (using the macros extension). I selected the current line, ran the text in terminal, then cancelled the selection.

So my main approach so far has been a number of variations on the `workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup` command to include this within a macro.

As a MWE, the following macro I have included in settings.json:

```json
"macros": {
        "runAndReturn": [ 
           "workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText",
           "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup" // <--- this doesn't work/do anything
       ], 
    },
```

For me, when I run this macro, it executes the current line as expected, but the cursor moves to the terminal and doesn't return back to the editor.

Comment: I would try adding a `delay` to the first command - if your macro extension can do that, if not there are some that do.  I bet that first command is really a number of commands behind the scenes and that is causing a problem.

Comment: Please provide the name, ID, and Visual Studio Marketplace link of the macro extension you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was reported here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173247

It was caused here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/305de596d216fb925e3cc298c0b67ad99ad0b6c2

It was fixed here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/173573

See the first link for some workarounds people found, which you can use while waiting for a version with the fix to be released:

- Using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to focus the first editor group (or the number of whichever editor group you want to focus).
- Found by [anderswe](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173247#issuecomment-1418131023): Using [the multi-command extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command)  with the following:

  > ```json
  > {
  >         "key": "cmd+enter",                           // or ctrl+enter
  >         "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  >         "args": {
  >           "sequence": [
  >             "workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText", // run line
  >             "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup", // shift focus back to editor
  >             "cursorDown" // jump to next line so you can spam cmd+enter
  >           ]
  >         },
  >         "when": "editorTextFocus"  
  > }
  > ```
- You can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> to toggle the visibility of the integrated terminal view.

Note that [since VS Code 1.82, you can control whether the terminal will be focused](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_82#_terminal-focus-after-run-setting) using the `terminal.integrated.focusAfterRun` setting.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new setting in vscode v1.82 that governs whether to switch focus to the terminal, accessible buffer or remain in the editor after running the `workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText` command.  See [GH Pull Request: add focusAfterRun setting](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/191505/commits/3b4fdca0cda60b5d79a3c95abb56184b0232341f).

The setting is

```
Terminal > Integrated: Focus After Run

> "Controls whether the terminal, accessible buffer, or neither will be
> focused after `Terminal: Run Selected Text In Active Terminal` has
> been run."
```

Options are:

```
none                // the default, focus remains in editor
terminal            // "Always focus the terminal."
accessible-buffer   // "Always focus the accessible buffer."
```